# Visual Studio failing to detect existing objects, even from within the same file. Project still builds

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, enums

I just reopened a project I haven't touched in a few months, and my copy of VS2012 is doing some strange things. I've seen it do these things before, but usually it works itself out after a Clean or after restarting VS.

I have a Common project, which is referenced by at least 2 other projects in the solution. I have a cs file that contains 2 enums, and a class. I reference those enums within the class, but VS gives me the little red underline that indicates a syntax error. 
"The type or namespace name "SourceTypes" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)"

The enum is literally located above this class. It is public. Also, if I do a build, it will build correctly. But the error comes back after the build finishes. Sometimes it doesn't build properly, and I have to build this project first without doing a build all. I have no idea why this reference has started doing this suddenly.

I also installed CodeMaid and AllMargins recently, but I don't think either of those could cause build errors.

Also, the common library is using Framework 3.5, because it is referenced by two other projects, one of which is SharePoint, and therefore 3.5, and the other of which is a WPF app, running 4.0 (not Client Profile)

Any ideas?

Update: Clearly the problem is that it doesn't recognize the namespace. In the using statement in multiple files, the namespace has the red line under it. Maybe I've got some kind of namespace conflict? But if I did, I would expect it to fail when I do an actual build, which it does not.

Solution: Feri got the right answer. By unloading the Common project, and then reloading it, the problem went away. All references to the namespace were corrected, and everything works smoothly again.

Comment: I would definitely have someone else try to build it that doesn't have the plugins installed just to rule that out.

Comment: Maybe it seems silly! but it has worked for me before in my VS2010. close your project and open it again. or try undoing and then redoing the changes.

Comment: I've tried restarting VS. If I get someone else to run this, they have to install WiX, and a bunch of other crap that will take forever. I'm going to try disabling those two extensions and restarting first.

Comment: I've disabled the two extensions. No luck. Coworker thought maybe I had left an old version of the assembly in the GAC. I deleted the existing version in the GAC. No effect.

Comment: Feri, I just tried unloading the project and then reloading it. When you said "close your project and open it again", I thought you meant VS. 

You solved it. You should submit that as an answer, rather than a comment, so I can give you an upvote and mark it as the answer.

Comment: I'm happy I helped you :) but i think some members don't appreciate putting my comment as an answer.

Comment: Uh, why? Isn't that the point? Someone Googles the question, and there is a clearly-defined answer at the bottom? You answered it, you should get the reputation points, right? The alternative is that I submit my own answer and get credit, which seems too self-serving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Feri got the right answer (but opted not to submit his solution as an answer). By unloading the Common project, and then reloading it, the problem went away. All references to the namespace were corrected, and everything works smoothly again. However, the problem seems to come back whenever I close/reopen VS. Unloading/reloading the project fixes it each time though.